# Cardinality relation between subsets of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

$G$ is an abelian group, $A$ and $B$ are non empty finite subsets of $G$. 
Set $A+B := \{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ and
$H := \mathrm{stab}(A+B)=\{g\in G \mid g+A+B = A+B\}$.

Prove that 
$$
|A+B|\ge|A+H|+|B+H|-|H|
$$
Please help me in finding answer.Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to maths.SE.  May I encourage you to [edit] your question to describe where this problem has come from and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: You should look up Kneser's Theorem and realize that there's a good reason as to why you couldn't solve this problem right away.

Comment: Here is the shortest proof I've found http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.3539v1.pdf